# Is there a way to Control the Build Artifact Name that is Saved in S3 from AWS CodePIPELINE

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

What I'm trying to accomplish is setting the Artifact Name that gets generated via the codepipeline *not* the codebuild. I understand that we can control the name at the codebuild level but I want it specifically for the codepipeline.

I have confirmed that the mechanism works as intended in the codebuild however I cannot find any information on whether or not this can also be used in codepipeline. So far my own testing has shown that its not.

Comment: Still not able to find relevant resources. Were you able to find an answer to this?

Comment: @sanjogjadhav I did not end up finding anything about this. I'm assuming its not possible.

Comment: @PabloMartiCordero Just to get question understanding clear, would like to have specific name for output artifcat for CodePipeline?